# Animate/zoom a focused custom view in tvOS

Tags: focus, tvos

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` in my tvOS app. It has a `UIImageView` and some `UILabel`s in it. I can get the cell to be focused by implementing the `UIFocusEnvironment` protocol without any issue, but I can't figure out how to give my custom cell the focused appearance. (Elevation and responding to user movement on the touchpad).

I'm aware of `UIImageView`'s `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` property, but that only elevates the image in my cell, not the entire cell.

Is there a way to make tvOS apply the (seemingly) standard focus appearance/behavior to my custom view or do I have to do it all manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update in tvOS 12.0+:** Check out new classes Apple has provided in [TVUIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvuikit)! You can now make custom views that have this focusing behavior!

————

I asked the same question on the Apple developer forums. Apple staff answered:

> For custom views you'll have to implement the focus appearance
>   yourself. In the focus update method you can do things like apply a
>   transform and use the [UIMotionAffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMotionEffect_class/index.html) API.
>
> ```
> - (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
>     if (context.nextFocusedView == self) {
>        // handle focus appearance changes
>     }
>     else {
>        // handle unfocused appearance changes
>     }
> }
> ```

I think it'd be pretty helpful to make a `UIView` extension to be able to apply the same behavior to any custom view.

Maybe they'd like for us to implement more interesting ways to display focus to the user? That'd be a good reason to enable this easily only for `UIImageView` (Not to mention that this behavior also adds simulated light over the `UIImageView`, which is beautiful, but maybe only makes sense for images).

Answer (score 0):

As specified in previous answers, there is no standard way, however there are 3 options for you:

1. **(RECOMMENDED)** Implement your own custom focus behaviour , that is similar to `UIImageView` tilting likewise:

   ```
   class MotionView: UIView {

    let motionEffectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.backgroundColor = .red
    addFocusMotionEffect()
   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   func addFocusMotionEffect() {
    let min = CGFloat(-15)
    let max = CGFloat(15)

    let xMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform.translation.x", type: .tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    xMotion.minimumRelativeValue = min
    xMotion.maximumRelativeValue = max

    let yMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform.translation.y", type: .tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    yMotion.minimumRelativeValue = min
    yMotion.maximumRelativeValue = max

    motionEffectGroup.motionEffects = [xMotion,yMotion]

    self.addMotionEffect(motionEffectGroup)
   }

   func removeFocusMotionEffect() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.removeMotionEffect(self.motionEffectGroup)
    }
   }
   ```

2. Make `UIImageView` to be dominant View in your cell `contentView` and then append your custom view to `imageView's` `overlayContentetView` so that your customView will animate alongside your `UIImageView` as follows:

   `self.imageView.overlayContentView.addSubview(logoView)`
3. Add suitable element from TVUIKit that has the behaviour, currently as of 2022, the `TVCardView` servers purpose well. Then add CardView as subview of your `UICollectionViewCell` on top of `UIImageView` or `TVPosterView` and it will coordinate its animations with them. You need to add your custom View as subview of `TVCardView`s `contentView`. The downfall is that `TVCardView` cannot really have clear background and you also canot change its round corners.

   ```
    class CardView: TVCardView{
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
    super.init(frame:frame)


    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    lbl.text = "Test Label"
    self.contentView.addSubview(lbl)
    self.cardBackgroundColor = .red

   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   }
   ```